# ObjectDatasource doesn't pass sortParametername

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I'm having trouble getting a GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource to sort properly.
The ObjectDatasource does not seem to pass my "sorting" parameter. Code below:

This is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdListing" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid" GridLines="none" CellPadding="2" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="10" PagerSettings-Mode="Numeric" UseAccessibleHeader="true" ShowFooter="true" OnPageIndexChanging="grdListing_PageIndexChanging">
    <RowStyle CssClass="odd" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" />

        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address" SortExpression="Address" />
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="center" CssClass="textBold" />
</asp:GridView>
```

My objectdatasource is defined like this:

```
DataSource = New ObjectDataSource()
DataSource.SelectMethod = "GetAll"
DataSource.SelectCountMethod = "GetAllCount"
DataSource.SortParameterName = "sortColumns"
DataSource.StartRowIndexParameterName = "startRow"
DataSource.EnablePaging = True
DataSource.TypeName = "MemberController"
DataSource.MaximumRowsParameterName = "pageSize"
```

In my class "MemberController", I have the following function:

```
Public Shared Function GetAll(sortDirection As SortDirection, sortColumns As String, pageSize As Integer, startRow As Integer) As List(Of Member)
    Dim _db As New MemberDb

    If pageSize = 0 Then
        pageSize = 15
    End If

    Return _db.GetAll(sortColumns, pageSize, startRow, sortDirection)
End Function
```

Pretty straight-forward really. It just passes the parameters to a class which calls the DB with these parameters.

But "sortColumns" is ALWAYS an empty string.

So I can click a column header in my GridView, and then the select method gets called once more, but the sortColumns attribute is empty. I'm having a difficult time finding out what's wrong. The GridView allows sorting, and all of the columns are defined like this one:

```
  <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Title" DataField="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
```

But the parameter 'sortcolumns' is always empty, and yet 'startrow' for instance is correct when I go to the next page. So the ObjectDataSource does seem to do its work, but not for the sortcolumns.

Any ideas please?